# GeoRedirection script not working properly

Tags: php, api, geolocation, ip

I am developing a country specific website, for which I thought to have a geo redirection installed at my php server. The basic approach is to record the incoming IP address in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and then use a geolocation database to convert that into country information. I did go with Maxmind geolocation service.
The final script that I came through with some google power and experiment power was as follows

### index.php

```
<?php

getCountry($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

function getCountry($ipAddress)
        {

                // get the country of the IP from the MAXMIND
                $country="";

                // include functions
                include("geoip.inc.php");

                // read GeoIP database
                $handle = geoip_open("GeoIP.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);


                // map IP to country
                $country = geoip_country_name_by_addr($handle, $ipAddress);

                // close database handler
                geoip_close($handle);

                if ($country==""|| empty($country))
                {

                        $country="Unknown";
                }


                return $country;


        }

$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, "$ip");

// Country name is not used so commented
// Get Country Name based on source IP
//$country = geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, "$ip");

geoip_close($gi);

switch($country_code)

        {
            case "US": header("Location: http://site1.com
    "); break;
            case "CA": header("Location: http://site2.com
    "); break;
            case "GB": header("Location: http://site3.com
    "); break;
            default: header("Location: http://site.com
    ");
    }


?>
```

I downloaded the **geoip.inc** from https://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/php-20120410/geoip.inc

and **GeoIP.dat** from http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

**BUT**
Something somewhere IS going wrong. The code doesn't execute, with a few errors each time. Have tried a lot many permutations of silly mistakes, but nothing worked. Calling the URL brings up the file geoip.inc's code on the URL.

Tried to find any similar questions on SO, but couldn't. A detailed help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to app a php extension to ensure the inc is processed as PHP

add function and call getCountry($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

Note some people may not have this server variable set or it be accurate - cos of proxy or something 
Make use geoip.inc.php and GeoIP.dat in same folder as script

Edited :  To amend you edited code

// include functions
   include("geoip.inc.php");

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$country_code = getCountry($ip);

switch($country_code)

        {
            case "US": header("Location: http://site1.com
    "); break;
            case "CA": header("Location: http://site2.com
    "); break;
            case "GB": header("Location: http://site3.com
    "); break;
            default: header("Location: http://site.com
    ");
    }


    function getCountry($ipAddress)
            {

                    // get the country of the IP from the MAXMIND
                    $country="";



                    // read GeoIP database
                    $handle = geoip_open("GeoIP.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);


                    // map IP to country
                    $country = geoip_country_name_by_addr($handle, $ipAddress);

                    // close database handler
                    geoip_close($handle);

                    if ($country==""|| empty($country))
                    {

                            $country="Unknown";
                    }


                    return $country;


            }
```